# Delete rows if Second value is greater than Value

Tags: excel, delete-row, vba

I have been collecting data  over the past few data from an energy metering project i have set up.
The values that are recorded are saved in a CSV file and then extracted through usb drive.
i have opened and assessed the CSV file in excel and the data hasnt been recorded how i would like.
Instead of logging once every minute it has logged every 7 seconds.
This has created a problem as the template csv file i have created to average these figures wont work now.

i am trying to create a VBA marco to assess all the data and where the second value is higher then 6 seconds, i want it to delete it for example:
here is some of the values i am working with:

16:29:05    PAC3    239.8030701 50.01350021 1073.719116 4.450771332 0

16:29:05    PAC2    239.2398834 50.01499939 3046.500732 12.62684536 0

Above is how i would like it to look.
but it currently looks like below where there are several entries under the 16:30 time

16:30:02    PAC3    239.6912689 50.06306076 1092.592651 4.229027748 0

16:30:02    PAC2    238.8809052 50.06230927 3535.760254 14.82234478 0

16:30:09    PAC3    239.8191681 50.07057571 999.7850342 4.125905514 0

16:30:09    PAC2    239.2037506 50.06982422 2644.371338 11.05446911 0

because it is logging every 7 seconds i am getting about 7 - 8 logs per minute per PAC

so where the second value is greater than 6 seconds i would like the whole row to be removed. and continue to cycle through the entire column and remove them. These cells are formatted into a time format but do contain a time and data value

I have searched for ways to complete this task but have found no solutions
any help appreciated.

Comment: So how about splitting the line into seperate values and use a filter, avoiding VBA?

Comment: they are separate values, the time, Pac, Volts and so on are in different columns, i have also put them in a table problem is their is about 13,000 rows total itll take too long to go through them all for the past 5 days, i have looked at the project and managed to correct the csv file to log only per minute. but i still need all these past few days worth of data in a readable chart.

Answer (score 1):

If you use =SECOND() function you can extract the seconds from the time value. Then loop up the column starting at the bottom and delete the rows that contain the values you don't want.

Comment: thanks i have added in a new column and used =SECOND() to extract them, i still need to write a VBA code to delete the rows greater then 6 seconds.

Comment: I still don't understand the need for VBA. If you add a filter, filter values greater than 6 seconds, delete rows all in one go. You will be done in 1 minute.

Comment: I guess it depends on how often you are going to do it. If it's once a month, I agree with @JvdV. If you do need VBA record what you do and then tweak the code from there.